# React native - error "Task 'assembleDebug' not found in project ':react-native-reanimated'"

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I've just upgraded from `RN 0.66`. to `0.67`, and now I'm getting the following errors:

> Android Studio build = `Task 'assembleDebug' not found in project ':react-native-reanimated'`
> React native build = `Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.`
> at makeError (C:\code\rn\xs\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
> at C:\code\rn\xs\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async runOnAllDevices (C:\code\rn\xs\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
> at async Command.handleAction (C:\code\rn\xs\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)

I've made all the changes to related to babel that are recommended here:
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/

Comment: Did you tried `cd android && ./gradlew assemble`?

Comment: that command gives me the following error:
./gradlew: line 188: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my error was not related to the RN upgrade.....it was instead because I upgraded react-native-reanimated from 1.13.4 to 2.4.1 (most recent) so it was no longer compatible with react-navigation-tabs.  Now I've rolled back that change the error is gone.  react-navigation-tabs@2.11.2 needs react-native-reanimated@1.13.4 (not higher)